# Remove right clicking quick access toolbar?

Tags: ms-access-2013

Is there a way to prevent users from right clicking the quick access toolbar? Either by unchecking an option or vba? Either by using I already unchecked Allow Default Shortcut Menus in the options, but it doesn't apply to the quick access toolbar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to create a custom ribbon interface using the USysRibbons table. My code is below. All I did was basically clear everything on the ribbon and quick access toolbar and added back a single import from Excel button in the quick access toolbar. It's important that `<ribbon startFromScratch="true">` has to be set to `true`.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <qat> 
       <sharedControls> 
         <control idMso="ImportExcel" label="Import from Excel" enabled="true"/>
       </sharedControls> 
    </qat> 
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```